# Breadth-first-search traverse the binary tree with unknown height

Tags: python, search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement an algorithm (Breadth-first-search or Depth-first-search) to traverse and extract data from a binary tree (with 2 direction WIN or LOSE) with UNKNOWN DEEP LEVEL (it can be up to 80-90).

What I need is all the paths as well as content of each node from root to leaves. I'm trying to find some way to trace the path, not only current path but all possible paths. And because whenever we finish at a leaf, we need to start again from root, we need way to check to see if :

- The path has been traversed before or not? (use queues or stacks????)
- Where does it stop? so we can pick up and continue from that (use flag to check???)

The tree:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/zkiznm.jpg]

So what I need to do is find all posible path from root A to leaves (V, Y, X, Q, Z, P, O, J, E, I, T, S, M)

And all possbile paths will be:

```
A -> C -> G -> L -> R -> V
A -> C -> G -> L -> R -> U -> Y
A -> C -> G -> L -> R -> U -> X
A -> C -> G -> L -> Q
A -> C -> G -> Z
A -> C -> F -> K -> P
A -> C -> F -> K -> O
A -> C -> F -> J
A -> B -> E
A -> B -> D -> I
A -> B -> D -> H -> N -> T
A -> B -> D -> H -> N -> S
A -> B -> D -> H -> M
```

Each node will have data I need to extract.

When we go to the leave, we will need to start over from the beginning, but we need to find some way to keep track of the paths we have traverse so we don't have to do it again since the height of the tree is not just 7 levels like this example, it may up to 80-100.

**#EDITED**
The reason I want to use BFS instead of DFS is because I want to avoid reaching at the leave level soon, since i will need to start at the beginning after that. If it haven't reach to the leave, it will be much easier to get as much data as possible, to build the tree.

I still thinking about the algorithm but I stucked:

Pseudo code:

```
Create an empty tree
Create an empty queue to keep track of nodes that need to be processed.
Create an empty arrray of array (A) to save path. This array will be built up with each child     array is a possible path:
[ [WIN,WIN,WIN,WIN,WIN,LOSE,WIN,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE],
  [WIN,WIN,WIN,WIN,WIN,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,],
.............................................................................................
  [LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,LOSE,WIN,LOSE]]
Create an empty arrray of array (B) to save flag. This array will have exact size with A but it will have 2 value 0 when we haven't visit that node, 1 when we visit it). So this array will change value from 0 to 1 when we visit node.
[ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
....................................................
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],

Add the starting point to the tree as the root node
Add the root node to a queue for processing

Repeat until the queue is empty (or finish):
  Remove a node from the queue 
  For child value WIN: 
    If the child hasn't already been processed: 
      Add it to the queue 
      Add it to array of array A
      Set 1 to array of array B
      Create an edge in the graph that connects the node and its neighbor
```

Any help would be appreciate! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are some confusing points in the question, if you please answer them, I can give you the algorithm. We can solve this problem using a hash map of stacks to store all the visited paths. Whenever we visit a new node we add it to the hash and store the stacktrace. Now this is a very inefficient approach, the alternative is reconstructing a tree with parent node.

If you don't know the algorithm at all. You can take inspiration from the following pages

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_2
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search

1) "What I need is all the paths as well as content of each node from root to leaves."

**You want to see all the paths upto leaves or only to the point element is found.**

2) "I'm trying to find some way to trace the path, not only current path but all possible paths."

**For each node there is only one path in a tree.**

3) The rest of the question makes me assume that you've not thought through the problem fully. If you just go through the first wiki link I've given you can easily see that breadth first algorithm solves half of your problem.

Comment: 1. I want to see all the possible path from root to leaves. In fact, I want to rebuild the whole tree for visualization purpose so I don't have to find something specific (element).

Comment: 2. Yes, for each node there is only one path, but I want to get all the path. 3. I read and understand about Breadth first search but I fail to figure out the way to apply it. And I haven't explain it clearly. I may add some pictures to make it more clear. I will do it soon.